# How to prove that singular vectors have uniform distribution on the sphere?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, svd, random-matrices

## Problem

I have a matrix
$$X = diag(x_1, x_2, x_3), \quad
x_i \sim N \left( 0, 1 \right) \quad
i = \overline{1, 3}$$
and $x_i$ are independent.

SVD is used to find singular vectors:
$$X = U \cdot \Sigma \cdot V^T,$$
where $V$ and $U$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is diagonal matrix,
such that
$$\Sigma = diag\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3\right), \,
\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \sigma_3.$$

I need to find distribution of matrix $V \cdot U^T$.
But first I need to find distribution of left and right singular vectors.

In question
[Singular vector of random Gaussian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870816/singular-vector-of-random-gaussian-matrix)
on this forum that singular vectors have uniform distribution
on the sphere of radius $1$. 
But I don't understand how to prove it.

## My solution (probably wrong)

I tried to show that distribution of $X$
is invariant with respect to rotations.
To do this we need an orthogonal matrix $A \, : \, A^T = A^{-1}$
and form new matrix
$$X' = A \cdot X,$$
so that distribution of $X$ and $X'$ would be the same.
Though, I've found out that they don't have the same distribution.
$$x_{ij}' =
\sum \limits_{s = 1}^s a_{is} \cdot x_{sj} = a_{ij} \cdot x_{jj}$$
as the matrix $X$ is diagonal.
Then the mathematical expectation
$$\mathbb{E} x_{ij}' =
a_{ij} \cdot \mathbb{E} x_{jj} =
a_{ij} \cdot \mathbb{E} x_j =0$$
as $\mathbb{E} x_i = 0 \, i = \overline{1, 3}$.
But the variance of $x_{ij}'$ doesn't equal 1:
$$Dx_{ij}' =
a_{ij}^2 \cdot Dx_{jj} =
a_{ij}^2 \cdot Dx_j =
a_{ij}^2 \leq 1.$$ 
It can be equal to $1$, but not always.

## Questions

What is the right way to prove the statement,
that singular vectors have uniform distribution
on the sphere of radius $1$?

Will the distribution of singular vectors change if diagonal matrix elements $x_i$ has normal distribution with expectation $a$ and variance $\sigma^2 \, : \,
x_i \sim N \left( a, \sigma^2 \right) $?
Am I right that then sphere would have radius $a$?
What if matrix $X$ isn't diagonal?

Comment: The vector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ follows the multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mu = 0$ and $\Sigma = I_3$, the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. If $y = Ax$, then $y$ follows the multivariate normal distribution $N(A\mu, A \Sigma A^T)$ (does that look familiar)? The density of a multivariate normal variable $x \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ is proportional to $\exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2} (x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) \right]$. What is the density of $y$? That shows that $X$ is invariant under rotations

Comment: @JonWarneke Thanks, it helped to understand diagonal matrix case. If the vector $x = \left( x_1, x_2, x_3 \right)$ follows the multivariate standard normal distribution $N\left( 0, I_3 \right)$ then density of $y = A \cdot x$ is the same as density of $x$. If normal distribution is not standard, then the density of $y$ is proportional to $exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left( y -A \mu \right)^T \left( A\Sigma A^T\right)^{-1} \left( y - A\mu \right) \right\}$. Distributions of $x$ and $y$ are not the same. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's write down the probability density function (PDF) of the matrix $X$; this is just the joint density of $x_1, x_2, x_3$. Since those are independent normals, we have
$$
\prod_{i=1}^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x_i^2} \, dx_i = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x_1^2+x_2^2 + x_3^2)} \, dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(X X^T)} \, dX.
$$
Now, the singular value decomposition $X = U \Sigma V^T$ is actually a change of variables (up to ordering the singular values and signs of rows/columns of $U, V^T$, but let's gloss over that) $X \to (U, \Sigma, V^T)$. In other words, you can go from the probability density of the variable $X$ to the probability density of the *three* variables $U, \Sigma, V^T$. To do so, substitute $X = U \Sigma V^T$ into the PDF of $X$ to obtain
$$
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(X X^T)} \, dX = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^T \Sigma)} \, dX
$$
using the cyclic property of $\operatorname{tr}$ and the fact that $U, V$ belong to the orthogonal group.

Recall that the differentials $dX$ and $dU \, d\Sigma \, dV$ are related by the determinant of the Jacobian matrix for the change of variables; according to [this](http://qwone.com/~jason/writing/svdJacobian.pdf), we have 
$$
dX = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3} (\sigma_i^2 - \sigma_j^2) \, d\Sigma \, dU \, dV,
$$
so substituting gives
$$
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(X X^T)} \, dX = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^T \Sigma)} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3} (\sigma_i^2 - \sigma_j^2) \, d\Sigma \, dU \, dV.
$$
Now, note that the last term is the product of three PDFs (up to normalization): one for $\Sigma$ (namely $e^{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^T \Sigma)} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3} (\sigma_i^2 - \sigma_j^2) \, d\Sigma$), one for $U$ (namely $1 \, dU$), and one for $V$ (namely $1 \, dV$). Hence, those random variables (matrices) are independent, and moreover, $U$ and $V$ are distributed *uniformly* over the orthogonal group. Since $U$ and $V$ are independent and uniformly distributed over the orthogonal group, so is $V U^T$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it true to equate the density of three-dimensional vector to the density of a matrix?

Comment: Yes — the density of a matrix is the joint density of its entries

Comment: In article that you attached to the answer there are wedge products in $dX$. I have also found the same expression with wedge products for $dX$ in the [book](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Jacobians_of_Matrix_Transformations_and.html?id=Ci0hr2_nYjYC&redir_esc=y). But you have wrote $dX$ in more simple form and without wedge products. Can you explain, why it is possible?

Comment: From the linked document, are you missing a factor of $U$ and $V'$ in front of the differentials in the Jacobian of the SVD? If so then do we no longer have that $U$ and $BV$ are uniformly distributed over the orthogonal group?

Comment: Update: I'm not too familiar with the use of forms in this context, but it seems that (V' dV) ^(wedge) (as in the notation in the linked doc) is the Haar measure, so the conclusion may still be correct