# Singular vectors of random Gaussian matrix with non-isotropic rows

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, svd, random-matrices, geometric-probability

Suppose $G \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ has i.i.d. rows $g_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ for some diagonal matrix $\Sigma = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ where the diagonal entries satisfy $\lambda_1 \geqslant \dots \geqslant \lambda_n > 0$. Can anything be said about the distribution of the columns of $V$ where $G = U\Lambda V^T$ is the singular value decomposition of $G$? The following question considers the case when the entries of $G$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and shows that the singular vectors are uniformly distributed on a sphere of radius $1$:

[Singular vector of random Gaussian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870816/singular-vector-of-random-gaussian-matrix)

The proof capitalizes on the rotational invariance of the standard normal distribution but I don't think the same argument can be made here due to the form of $\Sigma$. Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?